# Not receiving an event fired from an .AS class

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, adobe, mxml

I have 2 files, 1 to dispatch the event and 1 to receive it (of course in addition to the event class itself).

I've done this before with both dispatching and receiving files being mxml, but this time `the dispatching file is an actionscript class`, and it's not working this time. Is it different for actionscript classes?

**Here's a dumbed down version**

The dispatching class dispatches the event as soon as it's created.

```
public class ASClass extends UIComponent{

     public function ASClass(){
        dispatchEvent(new MyEvents(MyEvents.FIRE_EVENT));
     }
}
```

in my main mxml app, I instantiate the `ASClass` which automatically dispatch the event as soon as it's created and the main mxml app should receive back. But something's not working.

```
protected function appCComplete(event:FlexEvent):void{
    addEventListener(MyEvents.FIRE_EVENT, gotEvent);
    var asClass:ASClass = new ASClass();

}

protected function gotEvent(event:MyEvents):void{
       Alert.show("got event");         
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
addEventListener(MyEvents.FIRE_EVENT, gotEvent);
```

is same as

```
this.addEventListener(MyEvents.FIRE_EVENT, gotEvent);
```

which listens for `FIRE_EVENT` dispatched by `this` object - your main mxml app. To listen for events fired from `asClass` object, you have to call addEventListener on that object.

```
asClass.addEventListener(MyEvents.FIRE_EVENT, gotEvent);
```

Thus, you cannot listen for events fired from the constructor. The following code shows the correct way to listen to the events fired by the `asClass` object (from anywhere but the constructor).

```
protected function appCComplete(event:FlexEvent):void{
    var asClass:ASClass = new ASClass();
    asClass.addEventListener(MyEvents.FIRE_EVENT, gotEvent);
}

protected function gotEvent(event:MyEvents):void{
       Alert.show("got event");         
}
```

If you think about it, you can see that it makes sense. The constructor is used to create an object - event subscribers are normally interested in some actions/changes occurring to the object once the object is fully built and functional.

That said, you can pass a reference to `this` or the function to the constructor of `ASClass` and then assign that function as the event listener from within the constructor if you want.

```
    public class ASClass extends UIComponent{
        public function ASClass(listener:Function){
            this.addEventListener(MyEvents.FIRE_EVENT, listener);
            dispatchEvent(new MyEvents(MyEvents.FIRE_EVENT));
        }
    }

    var asClass:ASClass = new ASClass(this.gotEvent);//pass the function.

//or

    public class ASClass extends UIComponent{
        public function ASClass(listenerObj:Object){
            this.addEventListener(MyEvents.FIRE_EVENT, listenerObj.gotEvent);
            dispatchEvent(new MyEvents(MyEvents.FIRE_EVENT));
        }
    }

    var asClass:ASClass = new ASClass(this);//pass the object.
```

Personally, I can't think of many scenarios where I'd want to go this way: consider some redesigning so that you listen to the events after the constructor returns.

Comment: @cooper There won't be any race conditions. The main point is that you should call event listener with the object that dispatches the event. Thus you should be calling `asClass.addEventListener` - you cannot do this before the call to the constructor as `asClass` is null at that point. Again, event listener should be added before the event is dispatched - but you can do this only after the dispatching object is created.

Comment: _it won't be slower than the ASClass dispatching the event._ I'm not sure I understand you here..